# How to find K smallest values using quick sort

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

The problem is simple if I sort all the values and pick the fist K values. But it wastes too much time because maybe the smallest K values has been sorted before the whole array is sorted. I think the way to solve this problem is to add a flag in the code, but I can not figure out how to put the flag to judge whether the smallest k values has been sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [random selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm) to solve this problem with O(n) time. In the end, just return sub-array from 0 to k.

Comment: Is that means to sort the whole array is a must?

Comment: No, in random selection algorithm, it doesn't sort whole array, in the end, the K smallest values just in the left side of Array[K]. So you just need to return sub-array from 0 to K. It just uses the partition idea of quick sort, but has a very excellent expected running time

Comment: I have read the wiki, I know the idea about solving this problem. Thx for your help

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem can be solved by finding the kth smallest value. Suppose the signature of the function `partition` in quicksort is `int partition(int* array, int start, int end)`, here is pseudocode which illustrate the basic idea:

```
int select(int[] a, int start, int end, int k)
{
    j = partition(a,start,end);

    if( k == j)
        return a[j];
    if( k < j )
        select(a,start,j-1,k);
    if( k > j )
        select(a,j+1,end,k-j);
}

index = select(a, 0, length_of_a, k);
```

Then a[0...index] is the first k smallest values in array a. You can further sort a[0...index] if you want them sorted.