# Getting largest k elements in an array outputted in sorted order in O(n + klogk) using heaps?

Tags: heap, big-o

I'm trying to get the runtime of my algorithm down to O(n + klogk), but I can't seem to do this. I'm getting O(n + nlogk) by using a min heap. Basically algorithm is as follows:

1. Build a Min Heap MH of the first k elements (arr[0] to arr[k-1]) of the given array. O(k)
2. For each element, after the kth element (arr[k] to arr[n-1]), compare it with root of MH. O((n-k)logk)
3. Finally, MH has k largest elements and root of the MH is the kth largest element. Call extractMin k times to get O(klogk).

This gets me O(k + (n-k)Logk + kLogk), which equals O(k + nlogk). But I need O(n + klogk).

I don't know what to do to get it faster using the min heap. Any suggestions?

Comment: show your actual code.

Comment: I don't need to code up anything, I need to design an algorithm. @Alan

Comment: O(k + n log k) is the best you can do with a heap. [Quickselect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect) is the way to go if you want O(n + k log k).

Comment: @Jim Mischel What if I use 2 max heaps and a seperate array which will hold the k largest elements. The first heap gets built like normal. O(n) here. The second heap at first just holds the root of the first heap. We remove the root from the second heap, and add the two child nodes from the first tree that were associated with this removed root. The removed root's value gets put in the seperate array. After we do this k times, won't we have the largest k elements in the array? I think this is in O(n + klogk) time as well!

Comment: I'd have to think about that a bit. It sounds like you're making 2k insertions into the second heap, and I'm not completely convinced that what you describe will produce the correct answer. Note also that your worst case (when k >= n/2) results in that pesky n log k term again.

Comment: @Jim Mischel I ran across this solution online to find the kth smallest element. I believe we can alter it slightly to get the largest k elements. What do you think?

Comment: @Jim Mischel Build a min-heap of size n out of all elements of A (which costs O(n)) and denote it by H1.
We also keep track of a separate min-heap, denoted by H2, which initially only contains the
root of H1. At iteration i (1 ≤ i ≤ k − 1), we remove the minimum (which is the root) from
H2 and add the children of the node corresponding to it from H1 into H2. Iteration i costs
O(log i) since it consists one removal (takes O(log i) time) and at most two insertions ( takes
O(log(i − 1)) + O(log i)). Observe that the root of H2 by the end of iteration i represents
the (i + 1)th smallest

Comment: element of A. Thus after the last iteration, we can access to kth
smallest element from the root of H2. Note that the total cost is O(n) + summation from i = 1 to k  of O(log i) which is O(n + k · log k).

Comment: I understand the concept. And you're right that, *asymptotically*, the summation is O(k log k). But in the real world you're doing k removals from H2 and up to 3k insertions into H2, which, when k >= n/3, makes it worse than O(n log k). I don't think the "constants are ignored in asymptotic analysis" argument holds much water here. In addition, you're going to need O(k) extra space to keep track of where in H1 you obtained each of the nodes that placed in H2. Otherwise you won't be able to find the children.

Comment: I've done a bit of research on this topic. See, for example, http://blog.mischel.com/2011/10/25/when-theory-meets-practice/. One thing I found, which is pertinent to your proposed algorithm, is that it took twice as long to create a heap from n items as it did for the Quickselect algorithm to select the items. Both algorithms are O(n), but one is *twice as fast* as the other.

Comment: @Jim Mischel In this case I need to use heaps and have a O(n + klogk) runtime. In an actual world situation I would definitely not use something else, but this is for an assignment with a stubborn teacher. The extra space is negligible, it's the big O I'm worried about. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using this min-heap approach is that you have to constantly process the entire rest of the array, giving you an `n` factor in-front of the `log k`.

There is a way to reduce the work done in actually *extracting* the first `k` elements, by using a *divide-and-conquer* strategy similar to that of quicksort. This exponentially decreases the part of the array which has to be processed.

1. Select a random pivot element.
2. Partition the array into those bigger and smaller than the pivot, just as in quicksort. Say there are `L` in the left partition and `R` in the right.
3. If `k == L` then we are done: the first `k` elements in the array are the smallest.
4. If `k < L` then continue from 1, processing the left partition only.
5. If `k > L` then continue from 1, processing the right partition with a new value of `k' = k - L`.

In case the above description is vague (edit: it probably is), this method is very well known, and there are plenty of sources out there ([here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13716821/how-to-find-k-smallest-values-using-quick-sort) from SO, with code).

Assuming that in the average case the pivot approximately divides the array into two equal halves (this is also the ideal case), the time complexity recurrence relation is given by `T(m) = T(m/2) + O(m)`, which means that the above algorithm is **`O(n)`**.

After this, the first `k` elements of the array are unordered, so just sort them at `O(k log k)`. Therefore the total complexity is `O(n + k log k)`, as required.

Comment: I need that runtime in the worst case, not the average case though @meowgoesthedog

Comment: Well that's the best you can do. By randomizing the pivot position you *minimize* the probability that a worst-case scenario appears, but you are never totally immune to them. If the range of values is finite, you could try an `O(n)` sorting algorithm such as radix or bucket sorting.

Comment: hmmm okay, I'll keep working on it. My professor makes it seem like there's a heap implementation that gets you that runtime, so we'll see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: I'm a little skeptical of that because all heap operations will be on the *entire* array, which would give you the unsavory factors of `n`. I'm not dismissing the existence of a more optimal solution though.

Comment: What if I used a max heap? The largest k elements would be at predetermined positions, right? The largest element is at the root, the second largest is one of the two children, and this sort of pattern continues throughout the heap.

Comment: basically, is there a way to restrict heapify so that it only goes to the level where the last kth element is? Say we want the 50 largest elements. We build a max heap. Then we extract the max 50 times, and each time we extract the max we use our modified heapify so that it won't go past the level with the 50th largest element. We can find this level by doing log(base 2) of 50. Log(base 2) of k will give us the last level where our modified heapify is allowed to go. I'm not sure how I might implement this in code though...

Comment: nvm... realized that won't work. Maybe I need 2 heaps? I'm outta ideas that this point.